# How to generate smaller lists from a given list removing elements from the end one by one without loop?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, chunks

Given a sorted list of natural numbers for eg. `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, I am looking for an optimal way (without loop) using builtins to generate a list of sub-lists popping elements from end one by one as:

```
[[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: why do you need it without a for loop?

Comment: Why don't you want for loop ? Are while loop ok ?

Comment: please define your use-case more clearly, are you looking for a generator?

Comment: I am looking for an optimal way without any loop.

Comment: what do you mean by optimal? is recursion ok?

Comment: Any existing builtins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think there are any builtins that do this without a loop. That said, putting in a one-liner list comprehension is simple:

```
inn = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

out = [inn[:i] for i in range(1, len(inn) + 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go with `recursion`:

```
def add_ele(l,index,new_l=[]):
    if len(l)==index:
        return new_l
    else:
        new_l.append(l[:index])
        return add_ele(l,index+1,new_l)
l=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(add_ele(l,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

ONE LINER:

```
lambda nums: [nums[:n + 1] for n in range(len(nums))]
```